# What is the best way to write Kafka data into SQL Server using Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, apache-kafka, pyodbc

My requirement is to fetch the Kafka feed and store the data in the SQL Server. My  team doesn't own the Kafka and that is the only possible way i can think of to utilize the data for couple of my dashboards.

Now the Issue i am facing is that the speed in which data is coming from Kafka is faster than the speed i can write it in the SQL Server. This is resulting in the data delay.

I have read about the `executemany`, but my data is coming live and i have no batches to execute at same time.

I also tried with `threading` and `queue`, but that also not working as expected.

Can someone please suggest the best possible way to store this data and how can i speed up the data insertion ?

Comment: I think the answer should be to use Kafka Connect rather than Python

Comment: What option i have if i don't want to use Kafka Connect, How can i use pyodbc efficiently for this ?

Comment: I think you should re-consider using it, otherwise you can re-create part of its behaviour by manually creating batches yourself. And multithreading wont help unless you're writing to multiple tables at the same time

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal, have you got a solution? can you please share the code to insert data from kafka to SQL Server using Python.